# set ClientRequestContext property dynamically in ClientRequestFilter

Tags: java, jax-rs

hey everyone i just want to know how can we set a property on ClientRequestContext object to a dynamic value when using ClientRequestFilter in jax-rs web service. just like this

Suppose i have an object

```
MyObject obj=new MyObject();
obj.nmae="simon";
obj.vendor=209;
```

Now i want to call a web service for which i create a jersey client and for that client i created the filter.Now what i want to know how to get my object passed down to clientFilter so i can set ClientRequestContext property to myObject?

```
 @Provider
    public class RequestClientFilter implements ClientRequestFilter {

        @Override
        public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
            // how to set this to a variable value passed from a function in my code
            requestContext.setProperty("test", "test client request filter");
         //something along these lines
        requestContext.setProperty("myobj",obj);
        }
    }
```

this is what is happening

```
 MyObject obj=new MyObject();
    obj.nmae="simon";
    obj.vendor=209;
         ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
            config.register(EntityLoggingFilter.class);
            config.register(GsonMessageBodyHandler.class);
            config.register(ClFilter.class);
            // config.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 1000);
            config.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, 10000);

            try {
                Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
                WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8081/ServicB").path("Register")
                        .path("Service");
                System.out.println(webTarget.getUri());
                Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = webTarget.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                Response response = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.json("anything"));
                System.out.println(response.getStatus());
                String bresponse = response.readEntity(String.class);
                if (bresponse == null) {
                    System.out.println("null response");
                }
                System.out.println(bresponse);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
```

Comment: When _exactly_ do you want to set it, and when _exactly_ do you want to access it? Add some more context and even some code examples of what you are trying to achieve. This might even be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Please explain what the "X" is.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha i mean that i have created an object in my code and now i want to set the property of ClientRequestContext object to that object i have edited the question

Comment: When exactly is MyObject created in relation to the request being made? Can you show full pseudo code of what you'd like to happen. Right now it's still now clear the sequence of events that you want to happen.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha posting it in a sec

Comment: @PaulSamsotha edited my post

Comment: Filters can be registered with WebTargets. So what you can do is register a new instance of the filter with each separate request. And just pass the object to the filter constructor.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha would be so kind of you if you can provide an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register the filter as a class or an instance. If `MyObject` is just a one time object, you can simply pass the object through the constructor of the filter and then register it.

```
config.register(new RequestClientFilter(myObject));
```

If `MyObject` will change for each request, then you can also register the filter with the `WebTarget` instead. So with each different request, you can use a different object.

```
Response response1 = client.target(uri)
    .register(new RequestClientFilter(myObjectOne))
    .request()
    .get();
Response response2 = client.target(uri)
    .register(new RequestClientFilter(myObjectTwo))
    .request()
    .get();
```

Comment: thanks very much but i have read that filters are initiated at application startup and not for every request so how does this works i mean it is working but i wanna know how?

Comment: You're thinking of server side filters. Client side filters are different. WebTargets are independent for each request and can get their own set of filters.

Comment: ok so how will i access a property set in client request filter at the server request filter's side i.e a property set by ClientRequestContext will become available to a ContainerRequestContext how?

Comment: These are completely different contexts and have no relation. You can't access the property from the server filter request context.

Comment: Maybe you have a misunderstanding of how it all works. Client and server are completely different entities and are in no way connected. They are completely independent of each other.

Comment: ok so now i wanna know is this possible to set a property in ClientRequestContext and somehow access it in the service the request is being made to?

Comment: Send it in a header and access the header on the server.

Comment: You should read my very first comment in your post about the "XY Problem." Next time you ask a question consider this and try to ask the about the "X" and not the "Y."